# Django NoReverseMatch 5

Tags: django, reverse

I'm getting this error, and I don't know why:

```
  Reverse for 'buildings.views.generate' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'new_id': -1}' not found.
```

Here is ( a part of ) my urls.py:

```
  url(r'^buildings/generate/new_building(?P<new_id>\d+)', 'buildings.views.generate'),
```

The view:

```
  @login_required
  def generate(request, new_id):
          session = {}

          if new_id == -1:
                  other_buildings = Building.objects.filter(utente=request.user, pronto=False)

                  if other_buildings.length > MAX_TEMPORARY_BUILDINGS:
                          return redirect('buildings.views.index')
                  else:
                          building = Building(utente=request.user, pronto=False)
                          building.save()
                          return redirect('buildings.views.generate', building_id=building)

          elif new_id >=0:

                  building = Building.objects.filter(pk=new_id)

                  if building.utente != request.user:
                          raise Http404
                  elif building.pronto:
                          return redirect('buildings.views.detail', building_id=new_id)
                  elif building.nome == None:
                          buildings= Building.objects.filter(pronto=True).order_by('utente')
                          session['buildings'] = buildings

                  session['building'] = building                        
          else:
                  raise Http404

          return render_to_response('buildings/generate/generate-index.html', session, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And here it is the code in the template "base.html" that generates the error:

```
  <li><a href="{% url buildings.views.generate new_id=-1 %}">New Building</a></li>
```

I can't see any errors, help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably this works for positive numbers.

`-1` does not match the specification for `new_id`:

```
(?P<new_id>\d+)
```

You'll need to make sure you match the `-` too. I think this should work (not tested):

```
(?P<new_id>-?\d+)
```